# Android/PHP JWT expiration

Tags: php, android, token, jwt

I've implemented system wide with JWT. Everything is working great except a key point, the expiration method.

```
Map<String, Object> header = new HashMap<>();
    header.put("typ", Header.JWT_TYPE);
    String compactJws = Jwts.builder()
            .setHeader(header)
            .claim("email", email)
            .claim("password", password)
            .setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, settings.getString("keychain", "password"))
            .compact();
    Request request = new Request.Builder()
            .url(SITE_URL + "secure.php")
            .post(new FormBody.Builder().add("data", compactJws).build())
            .tag("login")
            .build();
    okClient.newCall(request).enqueue(this);
```

eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiJ9.eyJlbWFpbCI6Imd1eSIsInBhc3N3b3JkIjoiZ3V5IiwiaWF0IjoxNDk3NTU0MzAzLCJleHAiOjE0OTc1NTc5MDN9.4GFSC_OCYzkCxGetTFKKxoUkbpxWi51ccoKtIpPjz6g

[image: JWT]

```
<?php
$jwt = $_POST['data'];
require_once 'jwt/src/BeforeValidException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/ExpiredException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/SignatureInvalidException.php';
require_once 'jwt/src/JWT.php';
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;
try {
  $decoded_array = (array) JWT::decode($jwt, base64_decode("password"), array('HS256'));
}
catch (SignatureInvalidException $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('user_id' => - 3, 'title' => 'Contact 3gcb19@gmail.com', 'msg' => 'SignatureInvalidException'));
  exit(0);
}
catch (ExpiredException $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('user_id' => - 3, 'title' => 'Contact 3gcb19@gmail.com', 'msg' => 'ExpiredException'));
  exit(0);
}
catch (UnexpectedValueException $e) {
    echo json_encode(array('user_id' => - 3, 'title' => 'Contact 3gcb19@gmail.com', 'msg' => 'UnexpectedValueException'));
  exit(0);
}
$email = $decoded_array['email'];
$password = $decoded_array['password'];
```

Always throws an UnexpectedValueException 
Remove the timestamps and it works fine on the php end

```
.setIssuedAt(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()))
.setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 3600000))
```

What am I missing here??

Comment: i think you have a timestamp in milliseconds in java and in php is in seconds because firebase uses time() when decoding. Try %1000 on your System.currentTimeMillis()

Comment: The System.currentTimeMillis() is turned into a java Date object

Comment: Looking at the firebase implementation, I see that it's throwing `UnexpectedValueException` for like 7 different reasons. Maybe you can log the message of that exception `$e->getMessage()` and find out what the problem is? [here](https://github.com/firebase/php-jwt/blob/master/src/JWT.php#L79) is the decode function in php